# Plugin to download attached media files?

Tags: media

I have a photo gallery site. Each post has 10-20 photos. I want to be able to offer a download of my photos on post-by-post basis in a single zip file. In other words a link to a zip file with all those photos zipped up. How do I do that?

Is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 1):

[David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php) has a php script that will zip files in an array. All that you would need to do is put all of the full size image src's in an array and pass them to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it programatically, I would zip up the images and upload the zip as an attachment with a link in the content area.

If you're set on zipping the files automatically, make sure you account for performance issues if your files are large. I don't know of a plugin that does this.

Comment: Performance issues will not have much effect if the zipping is done upon UPLOADING (meaning - only one time) and not upon end-user request. the cropping functions of wordpress (post_thumbnail for example) will probably crash much before a zip function if memory is lacking. I have (an unpublished) plugin to do that , if anyone is interested .